# How can i change date format in entity framework(C#) yyyy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: .net, entity-framework, date, format

```
public class Coupon{   public datetime startdate{get;set;}   }
```

Below model have yyyy/dd/mm:hh:mm:ss  format in entity framework by default but i want chage to dd/mm/yyyy So please help me

there is any attribute for date format

Answer (score 1):

When converting the DateTime instance to a string, format it like so (assuming a DateTime instance called dtObject):
`dtObject.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`.
Note that the formatting is case sensitive, so "MM" should be upper case while "dd" and "yyyy" should be lower case.

Comment: i know how to convert date to string in dd/MM/yyyy ,but i want to know how can i change date format in entity framework